# Unix Command - Find files recursively with lengthy line

Tags: unix

I need to find files having either 1 or more lengthy lines ( more than 5000 characters )

Answer (score 0):

Search recursive for files with at least 5001 characters with a regular expression and only show resulting filenames.

```
grep -Elr ".{5001,}" .
```